# Apple Watch and Tizen shared library

Tags: ios, apple-watch, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, apple-watch-complication

We would like to bring some functionalities of an home banking mobile application to smart watches; we are evaluating *Samsung Gear(Tizen)* and *Apple watch*.

Do you know if it is possible to share a core library between the two platforms (Tizen, watchOS)?
It would contain just a generic wrapper to the rest API, some error handling and obviously nothing platform specific like the UI.
Something like a ***shared c/c++ library*** targeted for each specific platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to RzR's comment, there are some tricky things in this approach.  Tizen is moving in the direction of supporting Xamarin.Forms which should have some chance of doing what you want (see https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-.net-preview). I don't, however, know if that support is planned for the Tizen Wearable profile. A generic (platform-specific) shared library in general turns out to be frowned on by both Apple Store and Tizen Store policies, so that's going to have a harder time working out. A Tizen web app, on the other hand, should have an easy time working with REST, that's the idea of those... but whether they can access any Samsung Gear-specific features (as opposed to generic Tizen Wearable features) if you need those is a question that would require some research.

Answer (score 1):

I am not apple wizard, but If I remember correctly iOS is only using static libraries (libfoo.a), but Tizen can use native shared ones and this can be bundled into TPK. Iotivity project is supporting both, you'll find some hints about bundling shared lib into package:

https://wiki.iotivity.org/tizen